# > The named parameter 'child' isn't defined. bottom bar flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and learning to create a chat page with a bottom bar. when I'm add bottom bar code in child container I'm getting below error. struggling to solve this. how t solve this properly appreciate your help on this. below I have mentioned the error.

> The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.

```
import 'package:doctor_app/screens/user_profile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import '../CustomUI/CustomCard.dart';
import '../model/ChatModel.dart';



class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();

}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  int menuItem = 0;

  List<ChatModel> chats = [
    ChatModel(
      name: 'Dr.James Albert',
      isGroup: false,
      currentMessage: 'Hey How you doing?',
      time: "4.00",
      icon: 'person.svg',
    ),
    ChatModel(
      name: 'Dr.Perera Kariyawasam',
      isGroup: false,
      currentMessage: 'Hey How you doing?',
      time: "10.00",
      icon: 'person.svg',
    ),
    ChatModel(
      name: 'Dr.Anne Sigera',
      isGroup: false,
      currentMessage: 'Hey How you doing?',
      time: "7.00",
      icon: 'person.svg',
    ),
    ChatModel(
      name: 'Dr.Nirasha Wimalasuriya',
      isGroup: true,
      currentMessage: 'Plans for tomorrow',
      time: "7.00",
      icon: 'person.svg',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Doctor Chat "),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff05ABA3),
        ),

      child: Container(   //error
        height: 63,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  menuItem = 0;
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home_outlined,
                size: 34,
                color: menuItem == 0
                    ? Colors.white
                    : const Color(0xffC5C1C1),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.to(UserProfile());
                setState(() {
                  menuItem = 1;
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.perm_identity_sharp,
                size: 34,
                color: menuItem == 1
                    ? Colors.white
                    : const Color(0xffC5C1C1),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Get.to(ChatPage());
                setState(() {
                  menuItem = 2;
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.messenger_outline,
                size: 34,
                color: menuItem == 2
                    ? Colors.white
                    : const Color(0xffC5C1C1),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  menuItem = 3;
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: 34,
                color: menuItem == 3
                    ? Colors.white
                    : const Color(0xffC5C1C1),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff05ABA3),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(
          Icons.chat,
          color: Colors.white,),
      ),

      //body is here

      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: chats.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index)=> CustomCard(
            chatModel: chats[index]),

      ),



    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Scaffold doesn't have a property named `child` you have to use `body` instead.

Comment: I have already defined the body at the end of the code.

Comment: hi again :) you should replace `child` with `bottomNavigationBar`

Comment: you need to use `bottomNavigationBar` for the bottom bar instead of `child` as there's no `child` property in a scaffold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `child` property with `bottomNavigationBar`. Because, Scaffold class doesn't have child property. More info about Scaffold [Flutter Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)(Check out the properties section)

So it will be like:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(   //error
        height: 63,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          ...
```